# Symfony 5 and cookie

Tags: symfony, cookies

i'm looking for the way to handle cookies in Symfony 5 ... and there is nothing really usefull online.

To set a news cookie, i do :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
//.....
$cookie = new Cookie('email', $data['email'] ,time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
$response->sendHeaders();
```

And it works (don't hesitate to tell me if i'm not using the right way).

My problem appears when i want to get that cookie.

Actually, i do :

```
$cookie = $request->cookie->get('code_postal');
```

But i got the following error : "Notice: Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::$cookie"

Can you help me on that ?

Thank you.

Comment: You might be surprised to discover just how much Symfony [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-request-data) there really is.

Comment: I used 

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

$response->headers->setCookie(Cookie::create('foo', 'bar'));

No error given by SF but no cookie is created.. even if i respect the document.

What do u think ?

Comment: Try `$request->cookies->get('code_postal')` instead of `$request->cookie->get('code_postal')`

Comment: I don't if it is you that downvoted both answers that were posted to your question, but if so. You should probably add a reason why in the comments, so we can try to help you further.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you get is very clear.

> "Notice: Undefined property:
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::$cookie"

You are trying to use `$request->cookie` instead of `$resquest->cookies` with an "s". There is no `cookie` property in the `Request` object.

This should work

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('email', $data['email'] ,time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)));
// ...  
$cookie = $request->cookies->get('email');
```